# 100s of concurrent users trying to download files (asp.net C# application)

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I am trying to implement file download feature in asp.net application. The application would be used by say around 200 users concurrently to download various files.
It would be hosted on IIS 7. I do not want the application server to crash because of multiple requests coming concurrently.

I am assuming that by calling Context.Response.Flush() in a loop, I am flushing out all the file data that I would have read till then, so application memory usage would be kept uniform.  What other optimizations can I make to the current code or what other approach should be used in a scenario like this?

The requests would be for various files and the file sizes can be anywhere between 100 KB to 10 MB.

My current code is like this:

```
FileStream inStr = null;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
String fileName = @"C:\DwnldTest\test.doc";
long byteCount; inStr = File.OpenRead(fileName);

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.doc");

while ((byteCount = inStr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    if (Context.Response.IsClientConnected)
    {
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        //Context.Response.BufferOutput = true;                    
        Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Context.Response.Flush();                    
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance, only set the ContentType once, and call Response.End after the loop.

Comment: How big is your file? Might be more efficient to stick it into RAM if it is small enough, then you are hitting the IO far less.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Response.TransmitFile` to save server memory when sending files.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=testdoc.pdf");

Response.TransmitFile(@"e:\inet\www\docs\testdoc.pdf");

Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, you're not closing / disposing inStr.  That could affect performance.

Another more simple way to do this would be to use the built in method:

[WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx?ppud=4)

It should already be optimized and will take care of opening / closing files for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `FileSystemWatcher` class to check if the file was modified, and read it into memory only while such change was detected. For rest of the time just return the byte array that is already stored in memory. I don't know if `HttpResponse.WriteFile` method is sensitive for such file modification changes, or if always reads a file from given path, but this also seems to be a good option to use, as it is served by framework out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending an existing file to the client, consider using `HttpResponse.TransmitFile` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx).

Looking at the .NET code it seems that this will forward the file writing to IIS instead of reading/writing it in ASP.NET process. `HttpResponse.WriteFile(string, false)` and `HttpResponse.Write(string)` seems to do the same thing.

In order to verify that the file sending is relayed to IIS, at `HttpResponse.Output` property - it should be of type `HttpWriter`. The `HttpWriter._buffers` array should now contain a new element `HttpFileResponseElement`).

Of course, you should always investigate if caching is appropriate in your scenario and test if it is being used.